# Decipher How Many Characters in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uitextfield

How can I find out from Xcode how many characters are in a UITextField on Interface Builder.

I already have the IBOutlets all connected, I just need to know how to decipher how many characters are in a UITextField.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
[textField.text length];
```

That method returns a `NSUInteger`.